# Error: Method Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\From::__toString() must not throw an exception In symfony 2 application

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

> Pls i need to fetch the product entity based on the department it belong to but the department entity does not have a direct relationship with the product entity. Product is the great grand child of department in this manner
>   DEPARTMENT-> CATEGORY-> GROUP-> PRODUCT.

DepartmentRepository

```
public function findDepartmentProduct($id)
{
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder(['p', 'c', 'gc', 'ggc'])
        ->select(['p', 'c', 'gc', 'ggc'])
        ->from('Parent', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('p.children', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.grandchildren', 'gc')
        ->leftJoin('gc.greatgrandchildren', 'ggc')
        ->where('p.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('ggc.expire = :no')
        ->setParameter('no',0)
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery();
   }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
  /**
 * @Route("/department/{id}", name = "department")
 */
public function departmentAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $Department = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Department');
    $department = $Department->find($id);

    $Product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
    $customersChoiceProducts = $Product->mostView('20');


    $query = $Department->findDepartmentProduct($id);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        8/*limit per page*/
    );

    return $this->render('default/department.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'department'=>$department,
        'customersChoiceProducts'=>$customersChoiceProducts,
    ));
}
```

view:

```
<div class="link">
                <ul>
                    {% for product in pagination %}
                                <li >
                                  <a href="/brows/{{ product.id }}">
                                       <span>  <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(product, 'frontImageFile') }}" alt="" style="height:290px"></span>
                                       <h2 class="title">
                                           <span class="brand">{{ product.brand.name |title}}</span>
                                           <span class="name">{{ product.name|title }}</span>
                                       </h2>
                                        <span class="price-box">
                                            <span>
                                                <span data-currency-iso="NGN">₦</span>
                                                <span data-price="{{ product.price }}">{{ product.price }}</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        </div>
```

then i run the code i get error

> Error: Method Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\From::__toString() must not throw an exception
>   500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
->from('Parent', 'p')
```

Should be either:

```
->from('YourNamespaceYourBundle:Parent', 'p')
```

Or:

```
->from('YourNamespace\YourBundle\Parent', 'p')
```

With the correct namespace or bundle name in there for your app, of course.

Comment: look at the full detail of the department repository

Comment: `
namespace AppBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\Department;

Comment: class DepartmentRepository extends EntityRepository
    {
    public function findDepartmentProduct($id)
    {
        return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder(['p', 'c', 'gc', 'ggc'])
            ->select(['p', 'c', 'gc', 'ggc'])
            ->from('AppBundle:Department', 'p')
            ->leftJoin('p.Category', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c.Group', 'gc')
            ->leftJoin('gc.Product', 'ggc')
            ->getQuery();
    }
`